# probability shuffling decks of cards?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistical-inference, decision-theory

> You have the opportunity to invest $20 , with an uncertain return. To simulate uncertainty, we will use a deck of four playing cards consisting of two aces and two kings. The deck has been shuffled and placed face down on the table in front of you. You will now draw two cards, one after the other:
>
> If you draw two aces, you will receive $60
>
> If you draw an ace and a king, you will receive $\$30$
>   if you draw two kings, you will have to pay an additional $\$18$ and receive nothing
>
> - a) Let's assume that you are risk neutral for these dollar amounts. What is the expected value of the investment?
> - b) A special risk mitigation opportunity is available, for $\$5$. If you buy the opportunity, you will receive $\$6$ (and not have to pay $\$ 18 $ ) if the outcome is two kings. Should you buy it? Explain.
> - c) An expert card dealer can tell you what the first card is. He will charge $\$6$ for the information. Should you pay for the information?

Could someone please help me in verifying if the proposal answer is correct?

thats the proposal answer :

```
P(2 aces) = 2/4*1/3 = 1/6

P(1 ace, 1 king) = 2*1/2*2/3 = 2/3

P(2 king) = 1/6

a) Expected value = 1/6*60 + 2/3*30 - 18*1/6 = $27

Expected return = 27-20 = $7

b) Now investment = 20+5 = $25

Now, Expected value = 1/6*60 + 2/3*30 + 6*1/6 = $31

Expected return = 31-25 = $6

Now return is lower so we should not buy it.

c) If expert card dealer can tell you what the first card is, then probabilities changes:

P(2 aces) = 1/2*2/3 = 1/3

P(1 ace, 1 king) = 2*1/2*2/3 = 2/3

P(2 king) = 1/3

Now, Expected value = 1/3*60 + 2/3*30 - 18*1/3 = $34

Expected return = 34-20 -6(expert charge) = $8

This is higher return hence we should pay for this information.
```

Comment: You posted a question and then the corresponding solution? is the solution yours and you need help verifying if it's correct? or are you unsure of a particular step of the solution that's given to you?

Comment: Sorry, I Was not clear, i am looking for a help to see if the solution is correct

Comment: for some reason I can't check the accuracy of calculated odds, so ill consider your results correct. a) over one event you could either win or loose. over countless events you would have won an average of 27 per investment. therefore your expected investment value for neutral risk is 27. neutral risk means loose none/win none.

Comment: Parts (a) & (b) look fine to me.  Part (c) seems wrong (or at least, I don't understand what you're doing).  I thought the point of part (c) is that, after you pay \$6, you then get to decide _whether or not_ to invest.  That case-analysis seems missing.